# How can you override the 24 character mcrypt salt limit?

Tags: php, mcrypt

I would like to use a salt that has more than 24 characters with mcrypt.

```
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND));
```

However if I make $salt greater than 24 characters it throws this warning and uses a truncated salt at 24 characters:

> Warning: mcrypt_encrypt() [function.mcrypt-encrypt]: Size of key is too large for this algorithm

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: You shouldn't "like" to do things that are out of the inner workings of the encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

24 is the limit of this alorithm. Chars over 24 characters isn't used. But you can always trasnform your salt.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there an alternative encryption algorithm that mcrypt can use that you would suggest?

Comment: AES (a.k.a. RIJDAEL) is current standard of encryption. I think that it's the best one.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally MD5 the salt and use that otherwise you need to select a different algorithm.

Comment: MD5 is over 24 characters and I want 140+ character salts to make brute forcing virtually impossible.